# Firefox 48 for Android Disabled "Add to Reading List" on Long Press

Tags: firefox-for-android

In Firefox on Android prior to version 48.0, I used to be able to long press on a link and select "Add to reading list" from the pop-up menu. In version 48.0, the option has been removed? Why?

I sure hope the answer isn't that Mozilla was getting flack from advertisers who were upset that people could bypass the real page and just read the article content (imagine that!).

Answer (score 0):

1. go to reading page
2. look for book icon in address bar
3. switch to reader view
4. press add to bookmarks

It will be placed in the reading list.

Comment: Doesn't work for me unfortunately.